# Как подключить регистрацию?

Tags: php

Я вот создал регистрацию, а как подключить, не знаю.)) Помогите, пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что значить подключить? Создаете в БД таблицу со столбиками, которые вам нужны (id, ник, имя, дата рег. и т.п). Затем на странице регистрации делаете подключение к этой таблице, формами заносите в нее информацию. Затем можно создать страницу входа или блок, где бы отправлялся запрос к БД, на подлинность тех. данных, которые ввел юзер. И все.

Answer (score 0):

У проекта должна быть база данных с клиентами сайта, обрабатывать регистрацию можно формой со стороны html и post-запросом на файлик с логикой, а оттуда уже крутиться и создавать например сессии, если результат выполнения логики-1 , или если 0 - то посылать сообщение об ошибке